# Is it correct to display a button for admin and not for Firebase users?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Android app I have two type of users, admin (only one) and users. In the database I have a boolean `admin` like so:

```
db
|_ Users
    |_ uid
    |   |_ admin: true (only one)
    |_ uid
    |   |_ admin: false
    |_ uid
        |_ admin: false
```

When logged in, all users are redirected to MainActivity. However, if the user is admin, I display a button in the menu, otherwise I keep the button disabled for the other users. Basically, this button opens an activity where the admin can change some values in Firebase. Is there a clever way to do that? Can a regular user somehow open that activity and do what the admin can do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of security, you should assume that someone is able to reverse engineer and compromise the code of your app's code.  The only way to securely prevent users from doing things they're not supposed to do is by using a backend you control to check their permissions and perform actions if they're allowed.

Since you tagged this question google-cloud-firestore, it's worth noting that [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) also give a measure of control to determine who can make what changes in Firestore.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So you say I can keep that button in my Android app and use security rules to secure the data by not allowing the non-admin to write data in the database, right?

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you want in your app.  Just make sure access is controlled the way you require on the backend.